# Does PostgreSQL have buffered write table or plugin that can do this?

Tags: postgresql

Am looking for some kind of "buffer" table in memory for lot's of single write queries. The background is following: 
1) There is a bunch of separated daemon processes that produce lot's of write requests to postgres
2) The idea is to collect these requests into a memory storage and then write them to postgres by 1000 items chunks
3) I.e. not to overload database with ~100 write requests per second, but write ~1000 by one chunk once per second.

Clarification for some details. There are N separate daemon processes, each in own sandbox. They do not have communication through shared memory. Each process produces write queries. So there must be smth. like a collector for these write queries that flushes them by 1K-10K chunks to a permanent postgres table.

Such solution exists in ClickHouse database ("Buffer" engine). May be there is a postgres plugin that can do this? Current solution is to use RabbitMQ server for requests queue. But I want to avoid one more service that need to be monitored in our system.

Comment: Have you considered using prepared-statements? Or using batched statements? If yes, why did that not solve the problem?

Comment: you can buffer the data in your application, then batch insert it in a single transaction

Comment: Why not use a single INSERT statement that inserts a 1000 rows?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I can clarify some details. There are N separate daemon processes, each in own sandbox. They do not have communication through shared memory. Each process produces write queries. So there must be smth. like a collector for these write queries that flushes them by 1K-10K chunks to a permanent postgres table.

Comment: Are you seeing a problem, or is this purely speculative?  PostgreSQL automatically buffers writes except for the WAL logs.  If you use synchronous_commit = off, then it buffers those as well (at the risk of losing recent data after a crash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relational databases like PostgreSQL are equipped to deal with lots of requests efficiently. You can perform thousands if inserts per second if you have your system and your application set up correctly.

PostgreSQL buffers all your inserts in shared memory and writes them to disk during checkpoints. The only exception is the transaction log (WAL), which by default is to be written to disk for every transaction. This makes sure that every transaction can be recovered in case of a crash.

There are two things to consider:

- Don't open a new database connection for each request. Pool these sessions somehow. If that is not possible from the application, use something like pgBouncer.
- If you have many little transactions, then syncing the transaction log to disk will be the bottleneck. There are two ways out:

  - If you can afford to lose about half a second of committed data in the (unlikely) case of a database or operating system crash, set `synchronous_commit = off`.
  - If that is not an option, increase `commit_delay` from the default 0 and tune `commit_siblings` for your workload.

    This will make transactions take slightly longer, but reduced the number of sync requests due to transaction commit while still making sure that no single committed transaction can get lost.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I need to make some tests to compare different PSQL settings efficiency on write. Will post results later.